# visual studio window form and gridview

Tags: .net

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DELL-PC;Initial Catalog=BillingDB;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", con);
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BillingDb VALUES(@name,@company,@city,@province,@postal,@phone,@fax,@email)";

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name",textBoxNAME.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@company",textBoxCOMPNY.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@city",textBoxCITY.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@province",textBoxPROV.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@postal", textBoxPOSTAL.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@phone", textBoxPHONE.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fax", textBoxFAX.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", textBoxEMAIL.Text));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
```

my gridview name is dataGridView1 .. i want the data at the gridview to be refreshed on click of the above button .. what to do ?

Comment: i  have posted answer check it, i think it would be help to you.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
add this code after `con.Close();`.

```
 using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DELL-PC;Initial Catalog=BillingDB;Integrated Security=True"))
 {
      c.Open();
      using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM BillingDb", c))
      {
          DataTable t = new DataTable();
          a.Fill(t);
          dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
      }
 }
```